# How do I mock an IMAP server in Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

Does anyone know how can we implement dummy IMAP server to check my IMAP client performance...

Can anyone help me in this.. I am not able to find out any IMAP Server module in perl.. ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you searched, but searching for [metacpan imapserver](https://www.google.com/q=metacpan+imapserver) points you to [Net::IMAPServer](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-IMAP-Server).

But, this module is far from simple because IMAP itself is a complex protocol. This means writing a server which is both simple but also has enough of functionality needed in practice might not be possible. And if you need to check the performance of your client you better install a real server like [dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/), because otherwise you might be restricted by the performance offered by your simple test server.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Steffen ...  Even I got Net::IMAPServer but as you said this is complex.. I was not able to understand the functionality properly.. Anyway thanks. .And I will check dovecot...